# Why am I getting a NoneType error after reversing a linked list and processing the head of the new linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing code to answer the following question: "for two linked lists l1 and l2 that contain positive integers (and have at least one node), return their sum as a linked list. "

For example:

```
Input: l1 = [7,2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,8,0,7]
```

The way I am coding this is to reverse both linked lists, then add them (add this is how you would add two numbers)

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if l1==[0]:
            return l2 
        
        if l2==[0]:
            return l1
        
        #Reversing both linked lists l1 & l2
        prev = None
        pointer = l1

        while pointer:
            curr = pointer.next 
            pointer.next = prev
            prev = pointer
            pointer = curr

        prev2 = None
        pointer2 = l2

        while pointer2:
            curr2 = pointer2.next 
            pointer2.next = prev2
            prev2 = pointer2
            pointer2 = curr2

        #prev and prev2 are the heads of the reversed linked list(I've tested this) 


        #Creating a new linked list that is the addition of the two reversed linked list
        l3=ListNode(0)
        start_l3 = l3
        carry = 0 

        while prev or prev2:
            if prev.val + prev2.val >9:
                carry =1
            else:
                carry = 0
            s = prev.val + prev2.val + carry
            l3.next = ListNode(s)
            l3=l3.next
            prev=prev.next
            prev2=prev2.next

        if carry ==1:
            l3.next = ListNode(1)

        return start_l3.next
```

When I run this for the input given above, I get a "NoneType object has no attribute val for the line `if prev.val + prev2.val >9:`

Any ideas why this is? Because when I test `prev and prev2`; it does seem to return the reversed linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you cannot assume that *both* `prev` and `prev2` are not `None`. Your `while` condition only guarantees that at least one of them is not `None`, but not both. So that means you still need to have a `None` check inside the body of the loop.

There are also some other issues:

- `l1==[0]:` is not correct. The left side of this comparison is a *linked* list instance, while the right side is a *standard* list. These comparisons will always be `False`, and so you can just omit them
- You are adding the `carry` to the wrong sum. You should add the `carry` from the *previous* iteration to the current sum, so things are currently happing in the wrong order.
- The resulting list should be reversed. You can do this on the fly by *prefixing* each node to `l3`, instead of appending it. This will also make it unnecessary to create a dummy `ListNode(0)` before the final loop. You can just start with `None`.
- Your code mutates the original input lists. This will be acceptable on code challenge sites, and be efficient, but it is bad practice. The caller should not be unpleasantly surprised that the lists they provide as input have been reversed by a call to this `addTwoNumbers` function. You can solve this in several ways, but it is probably easiest to reverse them a second time to undo that operation.
- To avoid repetition of code, you should create a `reverse` function

I'll assume that the `ListNode` constructor can take a second argument for initialising its `next` reference:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt
```

Then the corrected code could be:

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:

        def reverse(lst: ListNode):
            prev = None
            node = lst
            while node:
                curr = node.next 
                node.next = prev
                prev = node
                node = curr            
            return prev

        #Reversing both linked lists l1 & l2
        l1 = reverse(l1)
        l2 = reverse(l2)

        #Creating a new linked list that is the addition of the two reversed linked list
        node1 = l1
        node2 = l2
        l3 = None
        carry = 0 

        while node1 or node2:
            added = carry  # The carry from the previous iteration should be used
            if node1:  # You must have this check
                added += node1.val
                node1 = node1.next
            if node2:
                added += node2.val
                node2 = node2.next
            carry = added // 10  # Simpler way to get the carry
            l3 = ListNode(added % 10, l3)  # Prefix(!) the new node

        if carry == 1:
            l3 = ListNode(1, l3)

        # Restore the input lists:
        reverse(l1)  
        reverse(l2)
        return l3
```

### Further remarks

Concerning the *prefixing* of nodes into the final list `l3`:

This is the main statement for doing that:

```
l3 = ListNode(added % 10, l3)
```

Let's break this down:

The constructor is called with two arguments:

- `val = added % 10`: this is one digit, so in case `added` is 14, this expression will evaluate to just 4 (the 1 will go to the carry).
- `nxt = l3`: this is the current (incomplete) list. The first time it is `None`.

The constructor then assigns these values as attributes of the new node that is being initialised:

```
self.val = val
self.next = nxt
```

So here we see that the value of `nxt`, is assigned to the new node's `next` attribute. As we passed `l3` as argument, we are actually doing:

```
self.next = l3
```

By that statement we effectively *prefix* the new node to the list: the new node becomes the *first* node of the list. Moreover, `self` acts as the *head* of that list, which is now one node longer. We want to keep track of this new head, and so we assign the new node back to `l3`:

```
l3 = ListNode(added % 10, l3)
```

As the first time `l3` was `None`, this will just create a one-node list, whose `next` attribute is that `None`. But the second time this is executed, we get a new node whose `next` refers to the "existing" node, so now we have a list of two... etc.

Sometimes it can come in handy to start a linked list with a dummy node like `ListNode(0)`, which then later can be removed. However, in this revised algorithm that would not help, and so we start with `None`, which after the first iteration of the loop will serve as second argument to the `ListNode` constructor, which in turn will use it to initialise the `next` attribute of the new node. This new node will remain the tail of the list as other nodes are prefixed to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Trincot. I have a 2 quick questions: 

1. Can None always serve the same purpose as a dummy variable? 
2. I do follow the logic behind connecting the L3 nodes; but also not quite- I can sort of see how “l3 = ListNode(added % 10, l3)” connects one node to another, but could you break it down into simpler terms to explain? 
In particular, I cant quite see how the nodes are being actually connected, where usually we have l3.next=…. to explicitly connect them

Comment: Sorry Trincot, I am also assuming by the above construction that the L3 nodes are being added in reverse order, so at the end we do not need to reverse L3? Again, I can't quite see how this is being achieved!

Comment: I added a section to my answer. Hope it clarifies it for you.

Comment: Thank you trincot- it makes perfect sense now. I missed the initialisation, and frankly didn't understand it before. But it makes so much sense the way you described it!

Comment: One more general question trincot if I may- for your code above, am I correct in understanding that the def reverse(...) will not run until you call l1 = reverse(l1)? And more importantly, is this true for any function within a function- that the inner function will not run unless you call it in the outer function?

Comment: Indeed, it is like that. In this case it could also have been an "outer" function. The difference here is that as an inner function it can only be called from `addTwoNumbers`. But this is not essential. Sometimes an inner function is interesting when it needs to access local variables that live in the outside function. In that case you cannot just move the inner function outside, but must add more parameters to get that data passed around. But again, that was not the case here.